# How do I explain current and voltage to a lay man?

Tags: voltage, current

A man asked me this question in suburban train when I told him that I am an electrical engineer. Of course I replied him that current is the flow of electrons and in order for the current to flow there should be a potential difference between them. But the man didn't know what electron or potential difference was either.

Comment: allaboutcircuits.com has really good explanation that compare electricity to water flow so most people can understand it. Just go to volume one and scroll through the pages

Comment: Electrocute him a few times. He'll soon get the gist ;)

Answer (score 8):

Offer him some water (or other beverage) to drink.

What happens when you drink a lot?
You have to pee, which means there's some pressure that urges you to pee.
This pressure is `voltage`.

Usually people do not pee in suburban trains.
There's a resistance against the pressure.

On a toilet, human brains lower the resistance and there's a flow of pee.
This flow is `current`.

The water analogy is a very common one (*I'm surprised you haven't heard about it*) It usually explains `voltage` as potential energy of water (from what height it's coming from), the `current` as the amount of water flowing and the `resistance` as the diameter of the tubing. (or something similar)

People go to great lengths with this analogy, finding substitutes for capacitors, inductors, etc.

You can find a lot of other analogies, because a lot of physics (our world) is driven by a **difference in a certain value** (different air pressure, different temperatures, ...) and **some value changing, lowering that difference** (wind blowing, heat exchange, ...).

Answer (score 4):

Along with the water analogy (which works quite well, esp with a bath being a capacitor)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This isn't as helpful for a true layperson, but someone who's taken enough undergraduate (or even high school) physics to know a bit of E&M might appreciate [this paper](http://matterandinteractions.org/Content/Articles/circuit.pdf), which presents a unified explanation of basic electrostatics and DC circuits. The relevant stuff is in sections II-B through II-E. The paper describes how electric fields produce varying distributions of surface charge on wires, which then steer current in the "right" direction. It's all based on the Coulomb force, which is pretty easy to understand. Here are a few of the figures to give you the idea:

[image: Battery and bulb]

[image: Electric field in a wire due to a capacitor points the wrong way]

The wire in Figure 5 is highly resistive, so the capacitor voltage and charge stay roughly constant.

[image: Induced surface charge creates its own electric field in the wire]

[image: The combined capacitor and surface charge fields create a uniform electric field inside the wire]

For someone with no physics background whatsoever, the pressure analogy is probably the best you're going to get. Don't say "potential difference"; someone who doesn't know what an electron is probably isn't ready for the concept of potential energy.

Comment: +1 One deficiency of the "water metaphor" is it leads to misconceptions such as "current is used up in a light bulb" and doesn't explain why there must be a return current path. A bicycle chain is a better metaphor, at least for single-mesh circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Just like water needs pressure to force it through a hose, electrical current needs some force to make it flow. A volt is the measure of electric pressure. Voltage is usually supplied by a battery or a generator and current is electricity in motion. It measures the amount of electrons that can flow through a material like a conductor.