# Amps and voltage

Tags: power, voltage, amperage

I am learning about electronics and micro controllers. I started with the basics and have came to the chapter in my book about currents etc. Now, I am a little confused with voltage and amperage. Am I correct in thinking the amount of amps is the amount of power, and the amount of voltage is the speed at which the power is sent? So if I have a 1A 1V charging port, and a 1A 2V charging port; the second will charge the device quicker? If so what happens if I put this up to 2A 2V?

Comment: The amp rating on the charger/power supply tells you how much current you CAN supply. If you hook a 2A charger to a device that takes 500mA, it will only run at 500mA. Power is voltage times current (P=I*V) so no, current is not power. I would look at allaboutcircuits.com they explain all of this stuff really well for beginners. Do not charge/power a device with the incorrect voltage. Unlike the current rating, if you supply 12V to a 5V device, it will receive 12V and will be damaged.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160439/how-do-i-explain-current-and-voltage-to-a-lay-man this question explains in simple terms what current/voltage are.

Comment: Why does this have an arduino tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the question that I. Wolfe linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current is current and power is power.

Apples and oranges, really.

Power is defined as:

$$ P = U \times I $$
or in words, if you find these symbols confusing or are used to different ones:
$$ power = voltage \times current $$

That means:

$$ 1V \times 1A = 1W $$
$$ 2V \times 1A = 2W $$
$$ 2V \times 2A = 4W $$

As you can see, your 3 scenarios have 3 different power values.
Yes, pumping more power into something will charge it faster.
However, reality limits how much current and voltage can be applied to devices.

The plug in your wall is able to deliver a lot of power (let's say 2000W), which means it would charge your phone very quickly. But common sense tells you that you cannot charge your phone directly with 230V, because it is not rated for such a high voltage. Power is not the only thing that you should consider.

Comment: If you are from the US or Canada, then U is V. So P = VxI

Comment: @efox29 didn't know that. Good point. Added formula with words to make it more clear.

Comment: Brilliant, this answered my question. Disappointed my book didn't have this formula...

Answer (score 2):

Volts measures the strength of the push, and Amps measures the flow rate.  Using a water analogy, Volts is like pounds per square inch, and Amps is like gallons per minute.

Neither EMF (the physical quantity measured in Volts) or current (the physical quantity measured by Amps) by themselves is power.  Actually power is EMF times current.  In common units Watts = Volts x Amps.